# Posting to Facebook page via CRON on the page's behalf

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

I have been posting to my Facebook page on the page's behalf via CRON (test mode). For such purpose I'm using Facebook privileges `publish_pages, manage_pages`.
My workflow is as follows:

1. Authorize my Facebook account for given permissions (only once)
2. Get pages I manage (where required page is among them)
3. Get access_token for page
4. Extend access_token for long_lived token
5. Publish post on page with long_lived_token

Since Facebook's new review&approval system you need to describe all the use cases for required permissions. My review request was denied. Their response was:

> Hello, You do not need these permissions if you are trying to post from your own blog to your own Facebook pages. Thank you very much for using Facebook!

My question is: how else am I able to post on Facebook page (which I created) offline (i.e. via CRON) on the page's behalf without using a workflow described above? This was the only working algorithm I was able to find tutorial to.

Comment: Likely the reviewer just phrased it wrong – of course you do need these permissions to post, but you do _not need to get them reviewed_ if only you are using this app. That is explicitly stated in the FAQ btw., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#roles